# How to extract this package archive

Tags: command-line, tar

I am trying to extract a certain file in the downloads folder and instructions given to me are as follows:

Type the following in terminal and it will be done

```
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-3.6.2_enUS.tar.xz
```

But when i type it in terminal it gives error:

```
tar (child): tor-browser-linux32-3.6.2_enUS.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

tar: Child returned status 2

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Did you change directory to where file exist (i.e. `cd $HOME/Downloads`)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did not save "tor-browser-linux32-3.6.2_enUS.tar.xz" in the folder where you are executing the tar command. If you are using a system with GUI, I would just recommend you to use `file-roller`, and to look for the right file and extract it in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `tar xpvf` to extract `.tar.xz` files.

```
tar xpvf [PATH TO ARCHIVE] -C [PATH TO EXTRACT]
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298368/how-to-unzip-tar-xz-files